# Newtonsoft JSON: How do I serialize some .NET objects that aren't strings, integers, etc... (like NetworkInterface)

Tags: vb.net, serialization, json.net

I'm trying to serialize information I obtain from `System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()`

`GetAllNetworkInterfaces()` returns a collection of `NetworkInterface` objects.  Serializing it basically returns no useful information.

```
    {
      "IsReceiveOnly": false,
      "Description": "TAP-Windows Adapter V9",
      "SupportsMulticast": true,
      "NetworkInterfaceType": 6,
      "OperationalStatus": 2,
      "Speed": 100000000,
      "Id": "{BCE79C39-232A-4483-AF64-1D26E3AA7C83}",
      "Name": "Ethernet"
    },
    etc...
```

Each `NetworkInterface` object has a function `GetIPProperties` which returns an `IPInterfaceProperties` object which in turn has a `GetIPv4Properties()` function which returns an `IPv4InterfaceProperties` object.

I see lots of examples of adding attributes to class properties to tell Newtonsoft JSON to serialize properties that aren't normal string, integer, boolean, etc...and even serializing the results from function calls, but I'm stumped on how I can indicate that for existing .NET objects.

My current and very painful workaround is to create my own `MyNetworkInterface` class with the properties I want and then manually assign properties like:

```
for each adapter as NetworkInterface in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
  my_custom_network_interface_object.some_property = real_network_interface_object.some_property
  dim ip_properties() as IPInterfaceProperties = real_network_interface_object.GetIPProperties()
  dim gateway_info() as GatewayIPAddressInformationCollection = ip_properties.GatewayAddresses
  for gw in gateway_info
     my_custom_network_interface_object.gateway.add(gw.ToString())
```

It seems like there should be a better way, and I'm just missing it.

Coming from a Python background, I feel totally lost in VB.NET.  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this properly, you'll first need to define some custom converter classes:

```
Class NetworkInterfaceJsonConverter
    Inherits JsonConverter

    Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
        Return GetType(NetworkInterface).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)

        ' prevent infinite recursion by temporarily removing this converter
        serializer.Converters.Remove(Me)

        ' build a jObject, starting with the properties we already have
        Dim jObj = JObject.FromObject(value, serializer)

        ' add the results from the GetIPProperties call as a nested object
        Dim adapter As NetworkInterface = value
        Dim properties = adapter.GetIPProperties()
        jObj.Add("IPProperties", JObject.FromObject(properties))

        ' we can add the GetIPv4Properties results also
        If adapter.Supports(NetworkInterfaceComponent.IPv4) Then
            Dim ipv4Properties = properties.GetIPv4Properties()
            jObj.Add("IPv4Properties", JObject.FromObject(ipv4Properties))
        End If

        ' you can expand this here if you need results from other method calls

        ' finally, write the jObject to the writer
        jObj.WriteTo(writer)

        ' restore the converter
        serializer.Converters.Add(Me)

    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
        Throw New NotImplementedException ' You can implement this if you have read usages
    End Function
End Class

Class IPAddressJsonConverter
    Inherits JsonConverter

    Public Overrides Function CanConvert(objectType As Type) As Boolean
        Return GetType(IPAddress).IsAssignableFrom(objectType)
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub WriteJson(writer As JsonWriter, value As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer)

        ' this one's pretty simple, but it's necessary to get the correct output
        Dim ipAddress As IPAddress = value
        writer.WriteValue(ipAddress.ToString())
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ReadJson(reader As JsonReader, objectType As Type, existingValue As Object, serializer As JsonSerializer) As Object
        Throw New NotImplementedException ' You can implement this if you have read usages
    End Function
End Class
```

Then you can wire them up to the default settings:

```
JsonConvert.DefaultSettings =
    Function()
        Dim settings = New JsonSerializerSettings()
        settings.Converters.Add(New NetworkInterfaceJsonConverter())
        settings.Converters.Add(New IPAddressJsonConverter())
        Return settings
    End Function
```

Then you can just convert normally:

```
Dim interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
Dim json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(interfaces, Formatting.Indented)
Console.WriteLine(json)
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing.  Thank you +Matt Johnson.

Comment: I keep getting a System.NullReferenceException at the line `jObj.Add("IPProperties", JObject.FromObject(properties))`.  If I call `Debug.WriteLine(JObject.FromObject(properties))` it throws the same error.  `properties` is definitely a valid object as I can `debug.writeline(properties.blah)` where blah is every property and function available to be called on the object.

Comment: hmmm... Perhaps it's choking on another subproperty.  Did you add both converters?  There may be another one needed also, depending on what the adapter data looks like on your computer.  The above works on my laptop, but each machine could vary of course.

Comment: Yes, I added both converters.

Comment: Could you paste the stack trace of the error in a [GIST](https://gist.github.com/) please?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's not much useful in there.  You should set a breakpoint after calling `GetIPProperties` to look at the results in the debugger.  Nulls are ok, as they would just get serialized as `null`.  You're looking for other complex value objects that might need special handling to be serialized properly (similar to `IPAddress`).  Keep in mind that JSON.net will try to serialize the entire graph of complex objects, so if a property multiple levels deep can't be serialized, you may get errors like an NRE.

Comment: Thanks again Matt.  I'll get to work on writing converters for everything.